# How to alert a user before items get expiry?

Tags: javascript

I've been given a small task that,

Every time if a user logs into his account, An alert or a message should display that these are the items which are going to expire in these many days or similar to that.

I am storing created date and expiry date into database and even showing the expiry date of the item to the user.

How to do this task in javascript or jquery??

If javascript then how?

Comment: what you have tried in jquery or java script can you show here..

Comment: also, what framework are you using / what is your middle tier technology?

Comment: Please provide relevant code. Also do you want to populate that alert message with text from your server? Or does this new date have to be calculated dynamically on the client side?

Comment: i am using struts1.2(java) framework. i haven't tried this yet. looking for logic or some example application which can help me out. The new date have to be calculated dynamically on the client side and alert him about the item expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you get started.

```
var expDate = new Date(Date.now() + 863600000),
    THREEWEEKS = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7 * 3; // milliseconds in 3 weeks

if (expDate.getTime() - Date.now() < THREEWEEKS) {
    alert("Expires in less than 3 weeks.");
}
```